# iPhone Accordion View

Tags: iphone, xcode, gridview, accordion, tableview

I have created a tabbed app (i dont use the storyboard) , the first tab is for login, the second should be a accordion view where messages with sender, receiver, text, etc. are in it.
The accordion view should be dynamically, so the items can dynamically increase (more messages = more accordion items).
In the header there should be only the date and the subject.
When I tap on the header, the item should expand and more details should be shown.
I've searched a lot how I can implement but I didn't found a good solution for my problem.

EDIT: This is an Accordion View example in [JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

Comment: By "accordion view" you mean an expanding/contracting table view, right?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will come in handy http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/14/iphone-uitableview-with-animated-expanding-cells/

Comment: ok, it was not the right solution, i can't implement it into a tabbed app -.-